# Bulk query job not returning all results

Tags: bulk-api-v2

I've been running the Bulk API v2 Query in my sandbox for a month now and it's been working great. I went to move things into production and I started encountering a terrible error. It seems my query is processing 14 records (as seen in the UI) but when I run /results to retrieve the results, I'm only getting one back.

```
SELECT Id,hed__Contact__c,Date_Unsubscribed__c,Subscribed__c FROM hed__Affiliation__c WHERE hed__Account__c = '0016g00000MrMeNAAV' AND hed__Contact__c IN ('0034V00002lr','0034V00002rm','0034V000036c','0034V000036b')
```

This is the query I'm trying to run (above).

However, it seems when I remove the first two contact ids and just pass the second two ids, my retrieve actually works. Any idea what's going on? My guess is that it would be data related, IE bad data causing the results to come back wrong, but Workbench is getting results just fine. If it is indeed due to bad data, I'm not sure how I can even use the Bulk API v2... How am I supposed to know if there are records that exist that I'm not getting back? I plan to create records when none exist, so I'd end up creating duplicates like crazy.

NOTE: Contact IDs above were truncated for security reasons.

Comment: I hope you have not hard coded those IDs in the query...? I mean, I hope you get these IDs and dynamically insert them into your call...

Comment: Yes they are dynamic, I just posted here as a sample, but the resulting query does in fact look like that, except it would have more contact IDs

Comment: I wonder if maybe SOQL for Bulk API cannot handle complex queries?